# QML [undefined] error

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I wrote a model to use it with QML and defined all properties properly:

```
class Model: public QObject {

    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString title READ title CONSTANT)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString request READ request CONSTANT)
    Q_PROPERTY(int first READ first WRITE setFirst NOTIFY firstChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int second READ second WRITE setSecond NOTIFY secondChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int minimumValue READ minimumValue CONSTANT)
    Q_PROPERTY(int maximumValue READ maximumValue CONSTANT)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool isRange READ isRange CONSTANT)
    Q_PROPERTY(int result READ result WRITE setResult)

    ...  setters / getters / signals ...
}
```

An then I wrote a code for an object which creates QML Dialog using previous model:

```
RangeInputDialog::Result RangeInputDialog::exec() const {
    QQmlEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine);
    component.loadUrl(QUrl("qrc:///ui-common/ui/RangeInputDialog.qml"));

    if (!component.isReady()) {
        qDebug() << "Could not load range input dialog";
        qDebug() << component.errors();

        return Result::Error;
    }

    QQmlContext context(&engine);
    context.setContextProperty("rangeDialogModel", &m_model);

    QScopedPointer<QObject> window(component.create(&context));
    if (window.isNull()) {
        qDebug() << "Could not instance range input dialog";

        return Result::Error;
    }

    QEventLoop loop;
    QObject::connect(window.data(), SIGNAL(closing(QQuickCloseEvent *)), &loop, SLOT(quit()));

    if (window->setProperty("visible", true)) {
        loop.exec();
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Could not show range input dialog";

        return Result::Error;
    }

    return static_cast<Result>(m_model.result());
}
```

`setContextProperty` binds Model with QML Dialog and after creating component it throws a bunch of errors:

```
qrc:///ui-common/ui/RangeInputDialog.qml:23:9: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString
qrc:///ui-common/ui/RangeInputDialog.qml:39:10: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString
qrc:///ui-common/ui/RangeInputDialog.qml:58:19: Unable to assign [undefined] to double
qrc:///ui-common/ui/RangeInputDialog.qml:57:19: Unable to assign [undefined] to double
qrc:///ui-common/ui/RangeInputDialog.qml:56:12: Unable to assign [undefined] to double
qrc:///ui-common/ui/RangeInputDialog.qml:70:14: Unable to assign [undefined] to bool
qrc:///ui-common/ui/RangeInputDialog.qml:68:19: Unable to assign [undefined] to double
qrc:///ui-common/ui/RangeInputDialog.qml:67:12: Unable to assign [undefined] to double
```

Does anyone know about this problem. 
I tried to use the same code in clear solution and then it works well.

**Solution**

Ok, I don't know why compiler did not throw any warnings, but removal of `const` specifier in `exec` method solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load your RangeInputDialog.qml file, it tries to access the `rangeDialogModel` context property but it doesn't exist yet, leading to those undefined warnings.

Additionally, when you are doing `QQmlContext context(&engine);` you are creating a new context, not retrieving the context that was used for the creation of your component.
You should get it by calling [`engine.getRootContext()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#rootContext) and then calling `setContextProperty` on that context so that your component can access the context property.

You should do the `context.setContextProperty()` 
before `component.loadUrl()`.

---

As a side note : Isn't all your UI in QML ? Displaying a QML dialog from c++ seems weird to me. The c++ business layer shouldn't be aware of the QML UI layer.

Comment: It changed nothing. C++ and QML connected by only the Model and QML is used for GUI only, it can not provide me sufficient performance.

Comment: @RealFresh Edited my post to add information on how to access the correct context.

Comment: I only removed const and the problem disappeared. Anyway, thank you for reply.

Comment: @RealFresh Please accept this answer or wright a new one describing how you solved the problem and accept it.